# Angular 2 - make imported modules accessible in child modules

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible to make modules, imported in a root module accessible in child modules?

For example, now I have root module with imported `FormsModule` & `ReactiveFormsModule` & custom `RoutingModule`:

```
// ...
@NgModule({
    // ...
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RoutingModule,
    ],
    // ...
})
```

But the problem is that in child `RoutingModule` components `ReactiveFormsModule` declarations are not accessible, so that I also need to import it there (in `RoutingModule` imports).

Is it a way to make all imported modules accessible for each other from top to bottom of import statement?

Answer (score 3):

Just like you imported export them from this module to be available for the child modules

```
exports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RoutingModule,
    ],
```

Comment: Hmm, just tried to export everything, but directives from `ReactiveFormsModule` are still not available in child module, they become available if I only import module directly in `RoutingModule`.

Comment: didnt get you. elaborate?

Comment: Maybe it happen in case of ReactiveFormsModule, but if I export it from the root module, it's still not available from the child module.

Comment: It should be accessible. Can you show your current module code?

Comment: I was replying to the op who said he wasn't able to get your code example to work. What you posted should work for him...

Comment: @DeborahK. I m very happy to hear it from you. This means a lot to me. :)